# string indices must be integers in python using Json

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, dataframe, typeerror

My requirement was to create a csv by extracting fields from Json file which is generatedbased on PDF extraction. I was able to get the values from it, but unable to move it into dataframe.
I am getting error of String Indices must be integers and append the text values from json into it.

My Json looks like this(JSON is extracted from PDF)
[JSON File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU3b9.png)

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open("C:\Test.Json", 'r') as file:
     jsonData = json.load(file)  

outputfile = "C:\Test.csv"

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['VendorName','AccountNo','Address']) 
        
for i in jsonData:          
    print("VendorName:", jsonData[i]['documentResults'][0]['fields']['VendorName']['text'])
    v1 = jsonData[i]['documentResults'][0]['fields']['VendorName']['text']
    df = pd.DataFrame([v1])
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print("V1: ", v1)
df2.to_csv(outputfile)

Getting Error at 
print("VendorName:", jsonData[i]['documentResults'][0]['fields']['VendorName']['text'])
String indices must be integers
```

Requesting help from experts as i was completely new to python.

Comment: `"C:\\Test.Json"` as backslash must be escaped, as `\t` is a tab character.

Comment: @JoopEggen Not really, as `'\t'` is not the same as `'\T'`. If that was the case then the error would have been different (ie file not found). OP is just iterating the dictionary wrong

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for that bit of knowledge. And yes the error was not caused by that. (Still would change the backslashes.)